# Edmond matching algorithm. How to start with a empty matching set?

Tags: algorithm, matching

I would like to perform the Edmond matching algorithm or Blossom algorithm on a Graph (example Graph in picture), but how to I start with a empty matching set?

The Algorithm work this way:

> Given: Graph G and matching M in G
>
> Task: find matching M' with |M'| =
> [M| + 1, or |M'| = IM| if M maximum
>
> 1 let F be the forest consisting of all M-exposed nodes; 2 while there
> is outer node x and edge {x, y) with y \in V(F), add (x, y} and
> matching edge covering y to F;
>
> 3 if there are adjacent outer nodes x, y in same tree, then shrink
> cycle (M-blossom) in F \cup {x, y) and go to Step 2;
>
> 4 if there are adjacent outer nodes x, y in different trees, then
> augment M along M-augmenting path P(x) \cup {x, y} \cup P(y);
>
> 5 in reverse order, undo each shrinking and re-establish near-perfect
> matchings in blossoms.

[image: example graph]

Answer (score 0):

You don’t begin the algorithm with an empty `M`. You have to provide one, generally by generating it with a greedy algorithm that parses all edges `e` of the graph `G` and adds each `e` to `M` if `M + e` form a matching.